# AMSlideMenu - call the left menu to open programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

Masters! I am new to objective-C. I find a open source of the slide menu on Github https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu. Everything is cool and works fine, except I wouldn't get the leftMenuBotton to show. I followed the tutorial completely, and still have no luck. But anyway, it was never my intention to have a Nav Bar. I want a button elsewhere I can call the method. I wonder if there is a way to call the left menu to open programmatically in other VC other than the MainVC thru a UIbutton.
 It seems it has some guide there, but I wouldn't figure it out. Could you please help me and show me some exameple? Many thanks!!!

Here is some of the customization found in the website:
You can use this methods in your MainVC.m if you want to open or close left or right menus programmatically:

```
- (void)openLeftMenu;
- (void)openLeftMenuAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)openRightMenu;
- (void)openRightMenuAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)closeLeftMenu;
- (void)closeLeftMenuAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)closeRightMenu;
- (void)closeRightMenuAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```

If you want do add left/right menu button, or enable/disable pan gesture in you pushed view controller, then just import "UIViewController+AMSlideMenu.h" and call this methods from your pushed VC instance:

```
- (void)addLeftMenuButton;
- (void)addRightMenuButton;
- (void)disableSlidePanGestureForLeftMenu;
- (void)disableSlidePanGestureForRightMenu;
- (void)enableSlidePanGestureForLeftMenu;
- (void)enableSlidePanGestureForRightMenu;
```

e.g.

```
[self addLeftMenuButton];
```

Where self is your pushed VC.

If you want to get menu's open/close callbacks, then set MainVC's delegate property, and implement protocol named `AMSlideMenuProtocols`.

```
@optional
- (void)leftMenuWillOpen;
- (void)leftMenuDidOpen;
- (void)rightMenuWillOpen;
- (void)rightMenuDidOpen;

- (void)leftMenuWillClose;
- (void)leftMenuDidClose;
- (void)rightMenuWillClose;
- (void)rightMenuDidClose;
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for using AMSlideMenu :)
In a view controller which where you want to add your menu button, you must import the AMSlideMenu category:

```
#import "UIViewController+AMSlideMenu.h"
```

After which, in action of your button (say -menuButtonTapped:)

```
- (void)menuButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self.mainSlideMenu openLeftMenu];
}
```